# Where can I find pre-trained Pathways Language Model (PaLM)?

Tags: natural-language, pre-training

I am amazed by the possibilities coming from the PaLM model after reading the following post: https://ai.googleblog.com/2022/04/pathways-language-model-palm-scaling-to.html . I was trying to find the pre-trained PaLM model and fine-tune with my own data. I have only found the implementation of the model architecture in Pytorch (https://github.com/lucidrains/PaLM-pytorch). However I would like to start from pre-trained model to save the computational resources. Do you guys know where should I look or I just have to train it by myself (on my resources it will take ages)?

Comment: Are you sure that you would even be able to run it? There are 540B parameters, so it seems that only for storing these you'd need more than 1TB of CPU/GPU RAM...

Comment: I am sure I would not :) I just realized the memory needs, based on the further research. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yeah it kind of sucks there is lots of these models for which it will probably take years before they are accessible on consumer hardware... But on the other hand there are several organizations like Eleuther or Big Science which provide open-sourced versions, so hopefully we could see these powerful models in distilled versions on huggingface someday.

Comment: My general conclusion after learning the complexity of such models is that we are really should be happy to have such a optimized machine inside our skulls :)